# Roslyn VisitArgumentList and VisitArgument how do I get the comma trivia?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, roslyn

If I use VisitArgementList(Node), Node is a comma separated list (x, y, z) , and VisitArgument(node) node is the stuff between the commas, x or y or z. But I am interested in the trivia (the linefeeds) that are attached to the comma. Is there a way to visit the comma and then recreate the list without losing the line feeds.

```
(x,
 y,
 z)
```

The code below is how I create the new line and all the linefeeds are missing

```
Public Overrides Function VisitArgumentList(ByVal node As CSS.ArgumentListSyntax) As VisualBasicSyntaxNode
    Return SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList(SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(node.Arguments.[Select](Function(a As CSS.ArgumentSyntax) CType(a.Accept(Me), ArgumentSyntax))))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the separators from the Node using GetSeparators

```
Dim NodeList As New List(Of ArgumentSyntax)
' Fill the node list and deal with Trivia
Dim Separators As IEnumerable(Of SyntaxToken) = node.Arguments.GetSeparators
```

Then there is another version of all the SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList methods and other list functions (SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList). They take a list of nodes (with trivia) and separators (with trivia) and even a version that includes the brackets or parentheses. Using these versions you can add the trivia to each element. One thing to note is that C# allows an extra separator, (ex. 
8 nodes, 8 separators) where VB requires one less separator then nodes (8 nodes, 7 separators). Filling the NodeList is easier in a loop then using a Select Function so that you can manage the trivia and deal with the missing Separator in VB and not all Trivia is allowed after a node, some has to be moved to after the separator. Below is a partial example

```
Return SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList(
    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.OpenParenToken).WithConvertedLeadingTriviaFrom(node.OpenParenToken),
    SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(NodeList, Separators),
    CloseParenToken.WithConvertedTrailingTriviaFrom(node.CloseParenToken)
    )
```